# AWSs sendEmailAsync not working in PHP application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have a PHP application where I can send mails via AmazonSES by using the [offical SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).

By default sending emails works when using the [`sendMail`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sesv2-2019-09-27.html#sendemail) method: (simplified):

```
$result = aws_client()->sendEmail([/* ... */]);
```

For the Async method I would like to use this:

```
$promise = aws_client()->sendEmailAsync([/* ... */]);

$promise->then(
    function ( $value ) {
        error_log( 'ok, fulfilled' );
    },
    function ( $reason ) {
        error_log('on no, rejected' );
    }
);

// $result = $promise->wait();

$promise->resolve();
```

I instantly get `ok, fulfilled` in my console but no email has been sent, not even after a couple of minutes.

When I use the mentioned line `$result = $promise->wait();` everything works as expected but the process takes much longer (of course because of the synchronism and this is why I like to go with the async method).

So is it just not possible to run an async process in PHP or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

AWS SDK *Async functions in PHP don't spawn a separate process for sending the email. Instead, they return a promise. This is useful if you need to do several slow processes at the same time, such as sending several emails. But the promise needs to be resolved (you need to wait for the response).

What I think is happening, AWS SDK connects to SES endpoint, starts sending your email and before it finishes, your script terminates. This also terminates the sending.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my script is using `ignore_user_abort(true)` and when inserting `sleep(3)` in the loop it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Does the execution take less than 3 seconds if you use `wait()`? Maybe it's not enough. Anyway, you can't expect the code to continue running without taking some special steps. Take a look at fcgi_finish_request PHP function (not always available). You'll be able to send output to a browser and then wait for the promise to resolve in background.

Comment: yes it does. I've even tried 10 seconds just for testing. no luck.

Comment: Try the `fcgi_finish_request`. If the documentation says the promise needs to be resolved, it's better do this.

Comment: This method is not available on all environments so I cannot use it. I'm looking for a working example with promises which should help me understand the whole thing better.

Comment: @Xaver you've already found a way that works - just use $promose->wait() at the end of your script. Check if `fcgi_finish_request` is available and call it if it is - this will make response faster. Use `flush` is the `fcgi_..` is not available. Basically, you can't avoid having to wait one way or another unless you extract sending the email to a separate process.

Comment: ok, thanks I'll do more tests. The main advantage of async should be "run and forget" which doesn't seem to work